# Ansible Vault and encrypted variables using include_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I need to have a file with passwords stored and encrypted using ansible vault, I have created an encrypted file named 'passes' stored in group_vars with this content after decrypting:

```
---
testvar: password
```

I have created playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: [machines]

  vars:
    include_vars: 
      file: group_vars/passes


  roles: 

  - role: someroletodeployafilewiththispass
```

The role just deploys a file with the pass from template which is:

```
using vaulted var {{ testvar }}
```

Each time I launch this using tower I get error message

> "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'testvar' is undefined"

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? There is no sign that my encrypted file is being decrypted by ansible. And the encrypted file I just pasted:

```
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
303965366239313330646366313238...
```

Maybe encrypted file should look different so Ansible will decrypt it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Explanation**

In your code, you have created a variable named `include_vars`, a dictionary with a key `file` and a string value `group_vars/passes`.

---

**Solution**

The correct syntax to define vars_files in a play is `vars_files` declaration:

```
---
- hosts: [machines]
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/passes
  roles: 
    - someroletodeployafilewiththispass
```

---

You can use `include_vars`, but it is an action module, which should be declared under the `tasks`, or in your case (because you want it to be executed before roles) in `pre_tasks`:

```
---
- hosts: [machines]
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: 
        file: group_vars/passes
  roles: 
    - someroletodeployafilewiththispass
```